# How to replace a constructor injected object with mocked object in spock

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spock

I know that the question is very big but I just want to clear the situation i am into.
I am working on an application that consumes the JMS messages from the message broker.
We are using camel route on the consumer side. All the object required in route builder are injected through constructor injection using spring .
I want to mock the behavior of the actual processing, Once the consumer receives the message from the queue. All the classes gets loaded via the spring configuration. 
Below are the three classes:
CustomRouteBuilder.java

```
public CustomRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder{

private CustomRouteAdapter customAdapter;
  public CustomRouteBuilder (CustomRouteAdapter customAdapter){
    this.customAdapter = customAdapter
    }
  public void configure(RouteDefinition route){
   route.bean(customAdapter);
   }

}
```

CustomRouteAdapter.java

```
public class CustomRouteAdapter {
  private Orchestrator orchestrator;
  public CustomRouteAdapter (Orchestrator orchestrator){
  this.orchestrator = orchestrator;
   }

  @Handler
   public void process(String message){
   orchestrator.generate(message) ;
   }
}
```

Orchestrator.java

```
 public class Orchestrator{
    private Service service;
    public Orchestrator(Service service){
     this.service = service;
    }

   public void generateData(String message){
    service.process(message);
   }
}
```

As per our requirement we have to load this configuration file and then write the functional test using spock.
Below is my

CustomRouteBuilderTest.groovy file.

```
 import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils
 import spock.lang.Specification

 @ContextConfiguration(classes=[CustomRouteBuilderTest.Config.class])
 class CustomRouteBuilderTest extends Specification{
    private static final String message = "Hello";
Orchestrator orchestrator;
@Autowired
CustomRouteAdapter customRouteAdapter;

def setup(){
    orchestrator = Mock(Orchestrator)
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(customRouteAdapter,"orchestrator",orchestrator)
    orchestrator.generate(message )
}

private String getMessageAsJson() {
    //return json string;

}


private String getMessage() {
    //  return message; 
}

private Map<String, Object> doMakeHeaders() {

    //Create message headers
}


private void doSendMessage(){
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    Map<String,Object> messageHeader = doMakeHeaders()
    byte [] message = getMessageAsJson().getBytes()

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext()
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(jmsBrokerUrl)
    context.addComponent("activeMQComponent",JmsComponent.jmsComponent(connectionFactory))
    ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate()
    context.start();
    template.sendBodyAndHeaders("queueName", message, messageHeader)
}

def  "test message consumption"(){
    given:
    doSendMessage()
}

    @Configuration
    @Import([FunctionalTestCommonConfig.class,CustomRouteBuilderConfig.class])
    @PropertySource(value="classpath:test.properties")
   static class Config{
    }
}
```

The problem that here is even though I inject the mocked object to the adapter using ReflectionTestUtils , I am not able to define its behavior correctly.
And when the message is received the orchestrator tries to process it.
My Requirement is that:
Adapter should be called from the camel route automatically which happens but
when the orechestrator.generate is called from the adapter then nothing should happen it should simply return.
But here nothing like that is going on.
Each time I send a message  the consumer(RouteBuilder) receives it and calls the handler function which then calls the

```
 orchestrator.generate(message)
```

function and the orchestrator starts processing and throws an exception from service level.
Any one can please help me on this.

Comment: are you sure that `CustomRouteAdapter` hasn't been proxied ? or that the field `orchestrator` is not final? do you have a NPE when executing your test ?

Comment: Earlier it was final. I removed the final modifier and then again tested the code. Still the same thing. As per this code I should have received the NPE but nothing. It call the service.process(message) and from there I get customized ServiceException.

Comment: check in a debugger, but you didn't inject correctly the mock, it should throw a NPE with the code you post :-) moreover, in groovy, you didn't need a ReflectionTestUtils, if the field is not final, you can write `customRouteAdapter.orchestrator = ..`

Comment: Sure let me try this. But iam afraid, that customRouteAdapter.orchestrator = mockedOrchestrator will work because my orchestrator is private in the actual code.

Comment: Now I am getting another problem,

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: orchestrator for class: CustomRouteBuilder$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ad2783ae

Even when I have remove private access specifier

Comment: The MissingPropertyException is resolved by changing private to public. But still no change still processing the service code and getting the same service exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your beans have been proxified by Spring, and this proxy use cglib (because you see `CustomRouteBuilder$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ad2783ae`).

If it's really the case, you didn't `@Autowired` in your test the real instance of your `CustomRouteAdapter` but a cglib proxy: Spring creates a new class, extending the realclass, and overriding all the methods of this class. The new method delegate to the real instance.

When you change the `orchestrator` field, you are in reality changing the `orchestrator` field of the proxy, which is not used by the real instance.

There are severals ways to achieve what you want to do:

1. add a `setOrchestrator` method in `CustomRouteAdapter`
2. create the mock in your spring configuration and let spring inject this mock instead of a real instance of Orchestrator
3. Inject the `orchestrator` in the real instance (ugly - I didn't recommend you that, it didn't help in the testability of your code!)

   ```
   customRouteAdapter.targetSource.target.orchestrator = _themock_
   ```

Comment: I tried the first option of adding a setOrchestrator in the customRouteAdapter and it worked. Thanks , thank you very much, I'll try other options too.